# What is the explanation of the python code which uses anonymous lambda to implement factorial function

Tags: python, recursion, lambda

This function really makes me flummoxed. Could anyone explain the key ideas ? It will be better if there are some examples to demonstrate how the function works.

```
from operator import sub, mul

def make_anonymous_factorial():
    """Return the value of an expression that computes factorial.

    >>> make_anonymous_factorial()(5)
    120
    """
    return (lambda f: lambda k: f(f, k))(lambda f, k: k if k == 1 else mul(k, f(f, sub(k, 1))))
```

Comment: That looks like deliberately obfuscated or golfed code. It would be a better use of your time to learn how good Python code works.

Comment: It's not even particularly well obfuscated. I prefer `A=(lambda A:A(A))(lambda A:lambda Α:Α and Α*A(A)(~-Α)or-~Α)`, which does the same thing. (Python 3 only.)

Comment: Probably you have to solve this exercise? http://cs61a.org/hw/sol-hw03/#extra-questions Let me say: geez

Comment: @MarcoSulla, I just do these exercises in my free time and I find some problems are really not easy.

Comment: @MarcoSulla: Odd.  Why would the questioner insist on using `mul` and `sub` rather than the normal infix arithmetic operators?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So rewriting in a longer form:

```
def make_anonymous_factorial():
  def func1(f):
    def func2(k):
      return f(f, k))
    return func2
  def func3(f, k):
    if k == 1:
      return k
    else:
      return mul(k, f(f, sub(k, 1)))
  return func1(func3)
```

And simplifying again:

```
def make_anonymous_factorial():
  def func1(factorial_function):
    def func2(k):
      factorial_function(factorial_function, k))
    return func2
  def factorial(recursive_func, k):
    if k == 1:
      return k
    else:
      return k * recursive_func(recursive_func, k-1)
  return func1(factorial)
```

Normally you could write factorial like:

```
def factorial(k):
    if k == 1:
      return k
    else:
      return k * factorial(k-1)
```

...but then this relies on factorial being able to reference itself by name. As an anonymous function, it can't do that, so it needs to be passed "itself" as an argument, so it knows whom to call.

The `func1` and `func2` are just setting up the system to call itself:

```
def func1(factorial_function):
  def func2(k):
    factorial(factorial_function, k))
func1(factorial)
```

This returns a function (`func2` as a closure, with access to the enclosing scope containing `factorial_function`). That `func2`, when called, will call `factorial(factorial, k)` and thus compute the factorial function.

Answer (score 1):

I write it here because I can't post indented code in comments.
@MikeLambert: the first part of your code is wrong. It should be:

```
def func1(f):
    def func2(k):
        return f(f, k)

    return func2
```

A word of explanation for Dimen61: this is because `lambda` functions are a "shortcut" for defining functions. So:

```
lambda x, y, z...: some_expression
```

is equivalent to

```
def someFunction(x, y, z):
    return some_expression
```

Returning to our "nested" lambdas

```
lambda f: lambda k: f(f, k)
```

the expression can be translated to

```
def func1(f):
    return lambda k: f(f, k)
```

and transforming also the other lambda you obtain the expression above.

I would also add that I completely agree with TigerhawkT3: this code is ugly, and even if Lambert unencrypted it, I consider it completely useless.

Comment: thanks for the correction, just fixed my post to add the 'return' statement!

Answer (score 0):

I second @TigerhawkT3's comment; that to code sth also most cryptically is possible does **not** imply such coding made a role model, let alone a must.

Bad code is just bad code and that's it.

But anyway - the method used is pushing lambda expressions meant to evaluate `n! = n*(n-1)!` on the invocation stack onto the way down from N (see the following code) to 1 and when `1` is reached, the stack is consumed top to bottom, and the lambdas expression are evaluated to the `int` they yield.

A little instrumentation shows this:

```
from operator import sub, mul

N = 5


def up_(k, f):
    print('  '*(N - k + 1), k, f)
    return mul(k, f)


def down_(f, k):
    print('  '*(N - k), k, 'f')
    return k if k == 1 else up_(k, f(f, sub(k, 1)))


def make_anonymous_factorial():
    """Return the value of an expression that computes factorial.

    >>> make_anonymous_factorial()(5)
    120
    """
    return (lambda f: lambda k: f(f, k))(
        lambda f, k: down_(f, k)
    )

print(make_anonymous_factorial()(N))
```

output:

```
 5 f
   4 f
     3 f
       2 f
         1 f
         2 1
       3 2
     4 6
   5 24
120
```